# Is there a function to calculate all possible sum of an array of number between them?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am currently facing a problem for a few days already.
I have a value, say `N = 0.8`
And an array of numbers, say `tab = [0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]`
Here we can see that the values at index 0 and 2 are 0.8, but I can't program this in a clean way, I end up with too many for loops (3 to be precise).

I tried to make a naive algorithm.
Create a variable `value = 0`
Two for loops, add the first element in the first loop and the others in the second one while checking that `value + tab[j] <= 0.8`, in some cases it works and in others, it's less than 0.8.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your requirements: do you mean you want to find all possible combinations from a given array that will give you a specific sum (e.g. 0.8)? Then this problem has `O(n ^ (n / 2))` complexity since you technically have to generate all combinations and check their sums. There are some shortcuts that you can take, i.e. abort further checking of a specific combination at a certain point once the sum >0.8.

Comment: Yes that exactly what i'm looking for, thanks for the last tips it's obvious but i didn't took it in consideration in my algorithm. Do you have link where i can read some code example ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  Do you just want to know if this *can be* represented as a sum of the values at distinct indices?  Of do you want to *find* all such ways it can be represented?  Or *count* all such ways?  Do you need the sum of any sized-group, or only pairs?

Comment: I want to know if it can be represented as a sum of the values at distinct indices, @ScottSauyet
Sorry if i wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recursive version.

We have base cases when the total is zero, and we return `true`, when the list of values is empty, and we return `false`.  If the first number in the list is too large, we drop it and recur.  Then we try using the the first number, subtracting it from the target and recurring with the remaining numbers.  If that doesn't work, we try dropping the first number and recurring with the same target.

```js
const canSum = (t, [n, ...ns]) =>
  t == 0
    ? true
  : n === undefined
    ? false
  : n > t
    ? canSum (t, ns)
  : canSum (t - n, ns) || canSum (t, ns)

console .log (`canSum (0.8, [0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]) //=> ${canSum (0.8, [0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5])}`)

console .log (' ')
console .log (`Trying 1 - 40 with [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]`)
console .log (`=======================================`)

Array.from ({length: 40}, (_, i) => i + 1) 
  .forEach (n => console .log (`[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13] ${canSum (n, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]) ? '*can*' : '*cannot*'} sum to ${n}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We can write something similar to find the first set that works:

```js
const findSummands = (
  t, [n, ...ns], 
  u = t > 0 && n != undefined && findSummands (t, ns), 
  v = t > 0 && n != undefined && findSummands (t - n, ns)
) => t == 0 ? [] : n === undefined ? undefined : u ? u : (v ? [n, ...v] : undefined)

console .log (`findSummands (0.8, [0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]) //=> [${findSummands (0.8, [0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]) .join(', ')}]`)

console .log (' ')
console .log (`Trying 1 - 40 with [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]`)
console .log (`=======================================`)

Array.from ({length: 40}, (_, i) => i + 1) .forEach (n => {
  const summands = findSummands (n, [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13])
  console .log (
    summands ? `${n} = ${summands .join (' + ')}` : `${n}  (no answer found)`
  )
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Comment: Hi !
Thanks a lot for all your explanation, i tested your code with the following array : `[0.005, 0.005, 0.050, 0.055` and it returned : `"canSum (0.11, [0.005, 0.005, 0.050, 0.055]) //=&gt; false"` i don't know how to "debug" the function your wrote to find a solution, i tried to sort it like this : `[0.055, 0.05, 0.005, 0.005]` but it wont work too.
Thanks again for your time @Scott.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a problem with floating point numbers.  We can try to add some small wiggle room if that is needed.